# Taking derivative of a partial bell polynomial?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, derivatives

I am trying to prove a statement that involves me taking the derivative of a bell polynomial.

Is there an elementary way to express:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}[ B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,....,x_{n-k+1})]
$$

Where you could treat the $x$ terms within the bell polynomial as functions of $x$

I mean I have some idea of what you would do, like perhaps relate it to Faà di Bruno's formula? But that doesn't seem very plausible.

Answer (score 1):

Let us replace: $x_{i}=a_{i}(x)$.

$$B_{n,k}(a_{1}(x),a_{2}(x),...,a_{n-k+1}(x))=\sum_{^{\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}j_{i}=k}_{\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i!j_{i}=n}}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i!^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}}$$

For abbreviation, we write

$$B_{n,k}(a_{1}(x),a_{2}(x),...,a_{n-k+1}(x))=\sum_{\pi(n,k)}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i!^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}},$$

where $\pi(n,k)=\pi_{n,k}(j_{1},j_{2},...,j_{n-k+1})$ and $\pi(n,k)$ is the partition of integer $n$ with exactly $k$ parts.

$$\frac{d}{dx}B_{n,k}(a_1(x),a_2(x),...,a_{n-k+1}(x))=\sum_{\pi(n,k)}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i!^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}}\right)'$$

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}f_{i}(x)\right)'=\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}\frac{f'_{l}(x)}{f_{l}(x)}\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}f_{i}(x)$$

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}}\right)'=\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}\frac{\left(a_{l}(x)^{j_{l}}\right)'}{a_{l}(x)^{j_{l}}}\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{l}(x)^{j_{l}}$$

$$\left(a_{l}(x)^{j_{l}}\right)'=j_{l}a_{l}(x)^{j_{l}-1}a'_{l}(x)=j_{l}a_{l}(x)^{j_{l}-1}a_{l+1}(x)$$

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}}\right)'=\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}j_{l}\frac{a_{l+1}(x)}{a_{l}(x)}\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}B_{n,k}(a_{1}(x),a_{2}(x),...,a_{n-k+1}(x))=\sum_{\pi(n,k)}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i!^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}j_{l}\frac{a_{l+1}(x)}{a_{l}(x)}\prod_{i=1}^{n-k+1}a_{i}(x)^{j_{i}}$$

Another formula is written in [Manipulation of Bell polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992807/manipulation-of-bell-polynomials) equation (1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but it still appears as a top hit when searching for derivatives of Bell polynomials, so might be good to answer it anyways.

I recently added the formula for partial derivatives of Bell polynomials to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Derivatives), which implies (using the chain rule) a nice formula for what you are asking:

$${\frac {d}{dx}}\left(B_{n,k}(a_{1}(x),\cdots ,a_{n-k+1}(x))\right)=\sum _{i=1}^{n-k+1}{\binom {n}{i}}a_{i}'(x)B_{n-i,k-1}(a_{1}(x),\cdots ,a_{n-i-k+2}(x)).$$