# Derivatives of $exp(f(x,y))$

Tags: polynomials, partial-derivative

I tried unsuccessfully to find this information in other posts, so I'll ask it here:

The $n$-th derivative of $e^{f(x)}$ can be given in terms of the complete Bell polynomials:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{f(x)} &= e^{f(x)}B_n(f^{(1)}(x),...,f^{(n)}(x))\\
&= e^{f(x)}B_n^{(1)}(f)
\end{align}
$$

where $f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$ and $B_n^{(1)}(f)$ indicates that we are considering the derivatives of $f$ with respect to its 1st argument.

I need the two-variable version of this formula, i.e.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^m}{dy^m}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{f(x,y)} &= \frac{d^m}{dy^m}e^{f(x,y)}B_n(f^{(1,0)}(x,y),...,f^{(n,0)}(x,y))\\
&=\frac{d^m}{dy^m}e^{f(x,y)} B_n^{(1)}(f)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}\frac{\partial^k e^{f(x,y)}}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial^{m-k} B_n^{(1)}(f)}{\partial y^{m-k}}\\
&=e^{f(x,y)}\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}B_k^{(2)}(f)\frac{\partial^{m-k} B_n^{(1)}(f)}{\partial y^{m-k}}
\end{align}
$$

So all I need to compute are the derivatives of $B_n(f^{(1,0)}(x,y),...,f^{(n,0)}(x,y))$ with respect to $y$.

We can consider the derivatives $f^{(j,0)}(x,y)$ as independent functions of $y$, so all in all I need a way to compute the terms:

$$
\frac{\partial^k}{\partial y^k}B_n(h_1(y),...,h_n(y))
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Markus is definitely appreciated, but I may have found a simpler way.

We expect the solution to be in the form

$$
\frac{\partial^{m+n}}{\partial x^m \partial y^n}e^{f(x,y)} = e^{f(x,y)}T_{mn},
$$

where $T_{mn} = \sum_{p,q}C^{mn}_{pq}f^{(p,q)}(x,y)$ is a polynomial in the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$.
I have worked out a recursive definition of $T_{mn}$:

$$
\begin{align}
T_{m0} &= B_m(f^{(1,0)}(x,y),\dots,f^{(m,0)}(x,y))\\
T_{mn} &= \sum_{r=0}^m\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{m}{r}\binom{n-1}{s}T_{rs}f^{(m-r,n-s)}(x,y)\qquad n\geq1
\end{align}
$$

The only issue is that I don't have an actual proof, I found this result by generating a lot of examples with Mathematica and by staring at them long enough.

Answer (score 2):

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d^m}{dy^m}}&\color{blue}{B_n\left(x_1(y),x_2(y),\ldots,x_n(y)\right)}\\
> &=\frac{d^m}{dy^m}\sum_{k=1}^nB_{n,k}\left(x_1(y),x_2(y),\ldots,x_{n-k+1}(y)\right)\\
> &=\frac{d^m}{dy^m}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{{j_l\geq 0,1\leq l\leq  n-k+1}\atop{{\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}j_l=k}\atop{\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}lj_l=n}}}n!\prod_{l=1}^{n-k+1}
> \frac{\left(x_l(y)\right)^{j_l}}{j_l!l!}\tag{1}\\
> &=n!\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{{j_l\geq 0,1\leq l\leq  n-k+1}\atop{{\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}j_l=k}\atop{\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}lj_l=n}}}
> \left(\prod_{l=1}^{n-k+1}\frac{1}{j_l!l!}\right)
> \frac{d^m}{dy^m}\left(\prod_{l=1}^{n-k+1}\left(x_l(y)\right)^{j_l}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n!\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{{j_l\geq 0,1\leq l\leq  n-k+1}\atop{{\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}j_l=k}\atop{\sum_{l=1}^{n-k+1}lj_l=n}}}
> \left(\prod_{l=1}^{n-k+1}\frac{1}{j_l!l!}\right)}\\
> &\quad\qquad\color{blue}{\times\sum_{{j_t\geq 0,1\leq t\leq  n-k+1}\atop{\sum_{t=1}^{n-k+1}q_t=m}}
> \binom{m}{q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_{n-k+1}}\prod_{t=1}^{n-k+1}\frac{d^{q_t}}{dy^{q_t}}(x_t(y))^{j_t}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> which is admittedly not handy, but could be used for further analysis.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use a representation  of  the  *[complete  exponential  Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Exponential_Bell_polynomials)*.
- In (2) we apply the *[general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#More_than_two_factors)*.

Comment: Thank you Markus for the time you've put into writing this, but I think I've found a more handy way to compute the derivatives (see my answer).

Comment: @Ziofil: You're welcome. Your approach looks interesting. Thanks for sharing it. I will have a closer look at it next weekend. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Letting
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^{m+n}}{\partial x^m \partial y^n}e^{f(x,y)} = e^{f(x,y)}T_{m,n}\qquad\qquad  m\geq 0,n\geq 1\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we prove OPs recurrence relation

\begin{align*}
T_{m,n} &= \sum_{r=0}^m\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{m}{r}\binom{n-1}{s}T_{r,s}f^{(m-r,n-s)}(x,y)\qquad m\geq 0,n\geq1\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain   from  (1) for  $m\geq 0, n\geq 1$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{T_{m,n}}&=e^{-f(x,y)}\frac{\partial^{m+n}}{\partial  x^m\partial  y^n}e^{f(x,y)}\\
> &=e^{-f(x,y)}\frac{\partial^{m+n-1}}{\partial  x^m\partial  y^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}e^{f(x,y)}\right)\\
> &=e^{-f(x,y)}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial  x^m}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial  y^{n-1}}\left(f^{(0,1)}(x,y)e^{f(x,y)}\right)\\
> &=e^{-f(x,y)}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial  x^m}\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{s}f^{(0,n-s)}(x,y)\frac{\partial s}{\partial  y^s}e^{f(x,y)}\tag{3}\\
> &=e^{-f(x,y)}\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{s}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial  x^m}\left(f^{(0,n-s)}(x,y)\frac{\partial ^s}{\partial  y^s}e^{f(x,y)}\right)\\
> &=e^{-f(x,y)}\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{s}\sum_{r=0}^m\binom{m}{r}f^{(m-r,n-s)}(x,y)\frac{\partial ^r}{\partial  x^r}\left(\frac{\partial ^s}{\partial  y^s}e^{f(x,y)}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^m\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{m}{r}\binom{n-1}{s}f^{(m-r,n-s)}(x,y)\left(e^{-f(x,y)}\frac{\partial ^{r+s}}{\partial  x^r\partial  y^s}e^{f(x,y)}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{r=0}^m\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{m}{r}\binom{n-1}{s}f^{(m-r,n-s)}(x,y)T_{r,s}}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim (2)  follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) and (4) we apply the *[general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)*

Comment: Thank you! I now also have worked out the multivariate version, I’m sure this proof can be adapted to that case.

Comment: @Ziofil: You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you again Markus, I mentioned you in the acknowledgements (I hope it's ok with you) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11722.pdf

Comment: @Ziofil: Oh yes, it's fine of course. Nice paper, thanks a  lot! :-)